# Need help identifying a plant

Tags: identification

So my cousin gave me this yesterday, but I don't know it's name. Would like to know so I could better take care of it. Thank you in advance. :-)[image]

Answer (score 2):

No need to answer my question, folks. I have since learned that this is a succulent of the genus Kalanchoe. So thanks anyway! Here's a link to a page where we can read up more about it: https://worldofsucculents.com/how-to-grow-and-care-for-kalanchoe/.